# How to have folding and unfolding of headers in orgmode file persist through emacs sessions

Tags: org-mode, persistence

Suppose I open an orgmode file and fold and unfold a bunch of headers, is it possible to let the folds and unfolds be the same next time I open emacs.
I feel the startup function wont be enough.

```
#+STARTUP: fold
#+STARTUP: nofold
#+STARTUP: content
#+STARTUP: showeverything
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in way to remember the folding state from one session to the next, but each headline can have a `VISIBILITY` property (possible values: `folded`, `children`, `content` and `all`) that can be set like this:

```
* Headline
  :PROPERTIES:
  :VISIBILITY: folded
  :END:

  ...
```

to set the visibility of each headline independently of any other headline and the global setting. But you'd have to manually set it (or implement a mechanism to automate the setting of it) in order to persist the folding state to future sessions.

Comment: thanks alot it will do for me